# Why in WEBVIEW Context the xpath generated by Appium isn't working using iOS simulator?

Tags: testing, webview, appium, ios-ui-automation, appium-ios

I want to know why in WEBVIEW Context the xpath generated by Appium isn't working using iOS simulator with java to write our scripts? 
Other question is there a way to make the code generated by appium recorder working in our java classes, because for now while we are in WEBVIEW there is no chance with appium we have to take a look into html code to create code.

> PS : I have already tried to change the context to NATIVE then turn
>   back to WEBVIEW_1 but no changes.

Comment: u can get help from this link https://discuss.appium.io/t/elements-in-webview-are-not-found-in-webview-context-ios/322/11

Comment: ok thank  for that